# R Studio - rearrange the column after group by

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like below in R Studio. I want to group by "group" and "ID", then create a new column which is the process flow of existing column. In the meanwhile, I want to remove the consecutive duplicated status.

[image]

```
group <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
status <- c("create", "new", "old","create","old","create","new","new","new","old","new")
d_f <- data.frame(group, ID, status)
```

Thanks a lot for your valuable time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by 'group', 'ID', `filter` out the `duplicated` run-length-id on the 'status' column and then `summarise` to concatenate the 'status' by `paste`ing in the same order of occurrence

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
d_f %>%
    group_by(group, ID) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(rleid(status))) %>% 
     summarise(status_flow = str_c(status, collapse= "> "))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group    ID status_flow          
#  <fct> <dbl> <chr>                
#1 a         1 create> new> old     
#2 a         2 create> old          
#3 b         3 create> new> old> new
```